# GeoServer SLD : Labels only showing in partial polygons

Tags: geoserver, labeling, sld

I have a GeoServer with a layer that is an SQL View containing a few polygons and a value. I made the SLD and I don't get why the label only shows up once in a while when the circle is partially out of view.

[image: Fully in view]

[image: Partially obscured]

My SLD is now like this :

```
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>TestPolygons</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>Label in circle</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#A1B8BA</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.7</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#096437</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
          <TextSymbolizer>
            <Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>CircleValue</ogc:PropertyName>
            </Label>
            <Font>
              <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-size">10</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-style">normal</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</CssParameter>
            </Font>
            <LabelPlacement>
              <PointPlacement>
              </PointPlacement>
            </LabelPlacement>
            <Halo>
              <Radius>1</Radius>
              <Fill>
                <CssParameter name="fill">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
              </Fill>
            </Halo>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </TextSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

I tried making a second Rule for the TextSymbolizer, I also tried putting the TextSymbolizer inside the PolygonSymbolizer (with and without the tag) and I always get this result. Any clue what I did wrong?

Comment: It works for me with another shapefile, are you using tiles? if so you may need to enable the partial vendor option with a specific placement

Comment: @IanTurton No tiling is used, just a plain wms call covering the entire extend. Could the fact that it's a SQL view layer be the problem?

Comment: maybe but it seems unlikely, can you turn logging up to GeoTools Dev and run it again then add the logfile section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of the behavior. By default an SQL view puts "Geometry" as a data type, when I changed it manually to "Polygon" the labels all drew correctly.